# Multiple condition in domain is not working - OpenERP 7 - Odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo, openerp-7

I am trying to use multiple condition for my domain but I got this error:

ValueError: Invalid leaf ('&', ('A', '=', True), ('B', '=', False)

I have no idea why. Everything looks well. I would like to have (A & !B) OR (C & !D )

This is my code (OpenERP 7):

```
        <field name="domain">['|',('&amp;',('A','=', True),('B','=', False)),('&amp;',('C','!=', True),('D','=', False))]</field>
```

What is wrong with my code? Some idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using extra brackets. Prefix Notation (AKA Polish notation) is all about discarding necessity of brackets. You should use proper ["prefix notation"](https://www.google.com/search?q=prefix%20notation) in condition statement. In order to correct a syntax, we have to remove extra brackets, so the above posted condition becomes `['|','&amp;',('A','=', True),('B','=', False),'&amp;',('C','!=', True),('D','=', False)]`. It'll solve the `Invalid leaf` error. See also my [answer to the similar question](https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/ayuda-1/question/how-to-write-a-domain-in-a-filter-solved-85100#answer-85108).